# Automatically re-indenting elisp code when adding or removing code before an indented block

Tags: indentation

Say I have a elisp code like:

```
(+ 2 3▮(+ 3
          4))
```

Is there a way to automatically re-indent the sexp after the cursor, when I add or remove symbols?

So after pressing `SPC 4 SPC`, I would automatically get:

```
(+ 2 3 4 ▮(+ 3
             4))
```

I can do this manual by calling `mark-sexp` followed by `indent-region`. Are there better ways of doing this?

Comment: I don't think there are any convenient default keybindings, but you could easily create some yourself.

Comment: I know but I'm specifically wondering are there any _better_ ways of doing this. For example how `electric-indent-mode` is much better than mapping `<return>` to `newline-and-indent`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of `mark-sexp` + `indent-region`, you can press `C-M-q`. This will call `indent-pp-sexp`. Not automatic, but a bit better than having to invoke two commands.

Or if you're using `paredit-mode`, press `M-q`. That will reindent the whole function definition you're in.

Comment: `(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook 'indent-pp-sexp)` works surprising well.

Comment: Looks good. That might be costly in some modes, but it's a nice approach nevertheless.

Comment: For Smartparens users, you can reindent the current defun with `M-x sp-indent-defun`. I bind this to `C-M-q`.

Answer (score 16):

## [Aggressive Indent Mode](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/aggressive-indent-mode/)

Since some people asked for it, I turned this answer
[into a package](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/aggressive-indent-mode/).

If you have Melpa configured, you can install it with

```
M-x package-install RET aggressive-indent
```

See the [Readme](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/aggressive-indent-mode/) for all the options, but the
simplest way to turn it on is:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'aggressive-indent-mode)
```

## The Old Answer

The following does auto-indentation only on elisp buffers. It has advantage of also working when you erase or yank stuff (instead of just typing). It's easy to add to other modes as well.

This function will indent whatever s-expression the point is currently inside.
You can bind it to a key if you'd like, but see below first.

```
(require 'cl-lib)

(defun endless/indent-defun ()
  "Indent current defun.
Do nothing if mark is active (to avoid deactivating it), or if
buffer is not modified (to avoid creating accidental
modifications)."
  (interactive)
  (ignore-errors
    (unless (or (region-active-p)
                buffer-read-only
                (null (buffer-modified-p)))
      (let ((l (save-excursion (beginning-of-defun 1) (point)))
            (r (save-excursion (end-of-defun 1) (point))))
        (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'message) #'ignore))
          (indent-region l r))))))
```

This hook will make it so that this function will be run after you
type anything, but only in elisp buffers. This should keep everything
always indented.

```
(add-hook
 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (add-hook 'post-command-hook
             #'endless/indent-defun nil 'local)))
```

Try it! **It works remarkably well.**

Also, following @holocronweaver’s suggestion in the comments, you can use
something like the following for c-like languages:

```
(define-key c++-mode-map ";"
  (lambda () (interactive)
    (insert ";")
    (endless/indent-defun)))
```

Comment: Would be excellent if this silenced auto-indent messages and better handled languages that end lines with semicolons.

Comment: @holocronweaver sure, I can try that. Which major mode has indent messages? And what's the issue with semi colons?

Comment: All the modes I tried on Emacs trunk produced indent messages, including elisp. Since semicolons end a line in many languages, until you type the semicolon the following line jumps about as though it were part of the current line.

Comment: @holocronweaver Silenced the messages. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks for the fix! One solution to the semicolon problem is to only indent in c-mode languages when a semicolon is typed.

Comment: Errors out if no end-of-defun.  Test with `emacs -q`, evaluate the code then type `(`.  This then removes it from `post-command-hook` so have to ensure code is always going to be valid.

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin Added an ignore error to prevent that.

Comment: This is really nice. @Malabarba would you consider releasing it as a full package?

Comment: @WilfredHughes Done! It is now a package on Melpa.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a pre-existing solution, but you can use `post-self-insert-hook` to accomplish this yourself:

```
(defun my-indent-next-sexp ()
  (interactive)
  (mark-sexp)
  (indent-region))

(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook 'my-indent-next-sexp)
```

I would worry about potential performance problems though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [el-fly-indent-mode](https://github.com/jiahaowork/el-fly-indent-mode.el), which is more well-behaved than `aggressive-indent-mode` when dealing with Elisp.