# Debug why a function is removed from post-command-hook

Tags: hooks

I am trying to implement the [auto-indentation snippet](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/385/115) posted by @Malabarba in one of the emacs SE questions.

From that post, below is the function that I am trying to add to the `post-command-hook`:

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(defun endless/indent-defun ()
  "Indent current defun.
Do nothing if mark is active (to avoid deactivaing it), or if
buffer is not modified (to avoid creating accidental
modifications)."
  (interactive)
  (unless (or (region-active-p)
              buffer-read-only
              (null (buffer-modified-p)))
    (let ((l (save-excursion (beginning-of-defun 1) (point)))
          (r (save-excursion (end-of-defun 1) (point))))
      (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'message) #'ignore))
        (indent-region l r)))))
```

But emacs is removing it from that hook as it seems to be causing some error.

If I call the function using <kbd>M-x</kbd>, it runs fine and doesn't throw any error; it just doesn't run when executed via the `post-command-hook`.

**Question: How can I find what's causing the removal of that function from the hook?**

I am using the following code to add that function to the hook only for elisp mode:

```
(defun endless/activate-aggressive-indent ()
   "Locally add `endless/indent-defun' to `post-command-hook'."
   (add-hook 'post-command-hook
             #'endless/indent-defun nil 'local))

 (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
           #'endless/activate-aggressive-indent)
```

Comment: What's the code that you're using to add it to `post-command-hook`?  After you run that code and you inspect the contents of `post-command-hook`, is the command listed?

Comment: @Dan I have updated the question will full code.

Comment: If you had visited the answer you linked to, you might have noticed I updated it with `ignore-errors `. :-)

Comment: @Malabarba Ah! How did I miss that; this was reinvention of the wheel. But I learned from that :) I used the code from your blog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hooks are intentionally removed from `post-command-hook` because otherwise a bad hook could lead to a condition where it becomes impossible to do anything, including figuring out what is going wrong, because the errors happens when ever the user does anything what-so-ever...

Comment: I believe that the question then I need to ask is how to make that function not throw an error.

Comment: `(when (and l r) ....)`

Comment: Thanks! I wrapped the function in `(ignore-errors ..)` and that also worked! I tried using `when (and l r) ..)` but that doesn't work as I think that the function errors out by the `(beginning-of-defun ..)` and `(end-of-defun ..)` calls.

Comment: I have removed my speculation on what is causing the error - that was obviously wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Don't just make the function on `post-command-hook` ignore errors. Instead, you can debug it to find out what the error is, and fix that.  To do that, you cannot use `M-x debug-on-error`, as using the debugger is (rightfully) disabled during `post-command-hook`.

What you can do is old-school debugging: Add calls to `message` to the function at various points, printing relevant info, to let you know just what is going on. Simple to do, and generally quick to debug. Open buffer `*Messages*` in a separate frame, and put point at the end of it, so you can see what's going on.

Have handy a `remove-hook` sexp or a sexp to restore the un-`message`d version of the function (e.g. in the secondary selection or a register), so you can quickly restore things if they get out of hand. ;-)

Comment: I agree. For this specific case, I didn't care about the errors and I wanted that function to work when conditions were valid.

Comment: I understand. But that's not a great thing to do. The less you have on `post-command-hook`, the better. Stuff that performs side effects or takes time, but which has no positive effect, is worth fixing or removing.

Comment: I really like the trick at https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2010-07/msg01410.html actually; it lets you use the usual debugger for post-command hooks.

Answer (score 2):

The usual `debug-on-error` doesn't work, but you can make it work :) A convenient way to debug these issues was proposed on [emacs-devel](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2010-07/msg01410.html) back in 2010:

Run `toggle-debug-on-error`, then advise your function to add an error handler to it:

```
(defadvice endless/indent-defun (around intercept activate)
  (condition-case err
      ad-do-it
    ((debug error) (signal (car err) (cdr err)))))
```

This will break into the debugger, just as if you were running the function as usual. The trick is from Johan Bockgård.