# Inserting before an after-string overlay

Tags: overlays

I'm using after-string overlays as in [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/temporary-text-in-window-location-with-no-text-to-propertize-overlay) to put text on the right hand side of the buffer, like this:

```
(let ((overlay (make-overlay (point-max) (point-max) (current-buffer))))
  (overlay-put overlay 'intangible t)
  (overlay-put overlay 'before-string
               (concat
                (propertize " " 'display `(space :align-to (- right-fringe ,(1+ (length text)))))
                text))
  overlay))
```

This works well, but if I position the cursor at the end of the buffer at insert characters, I insert past the overlay.

[image: I'm inserting past the overlay. Oh no!]

In the image, the check mark is my overlay, and the `x` after it is something I inserted by typing an `x` after the word `Type`, which was previously the last word in the buffer.

How can I stop this from happening? I'd like the overlay to permanently sit past all the actual text in the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use:

```
(let ((overlay (make-overlay (point-max) (point-max) nil t t)))
  ...)
```

The additional `t t` arguments will mark the overlays's boundaries as being "insert-before" rather than "insert-after".

Comment: This is almost perfect. One downside—I use a bar cursor, and even though insertions are insert-before, the cursor appears after the overlay. I tried the `cursor` property but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to try the `cursor` property again.  It's a tricky property to use, and I've often had to play with it for a while until it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that setting `'cursor t` as *an overlay property* has no effect when used in conjunction with an `'after-string` property.  However, it works if the STRING is *propertized*; e.g., `'after-string (propertize STRING 'cursor t)`.

**WORKS**:

```lisp
(save-excursion
  (end-of-line)
  (let ((eol-floating-column (+ (current-column) 10))
        (ov (make-overlay (point) (point) nil t t)))
    (overlay-put ov
                 'after-string
                 (concat
                   (propertize (char-to-string ?\uE001)
                                'display
                                `((space :align-to ,eol-floating-column)
                                  (space :width 0))
                                'cursor t)
                   (propertize (char-to-string ?\u00B6)
                              'face '(:background "gray50" :foreground "black"))))))
```

*BROKEN*:

```lisp
(save-excursion
  (end-of-line)
  (let ((eol-floating-column (+ (current-column) 10))
        (ov (make-overlay (point) (point) nil t t)))
    (overlay-put ov
                 'after-string
                 (concat
                   (propertize (char-to-string ?\uE001)
                                'display
                                `((space :align-to ,eol-floating-column)
                                  (space :width 0)))
                   (propertize (char-to-string ?\u00B6)
                              'face '(:background "gray50" :foreground "black"))))
    (overlay-put ov 'cursor t)))
```