# Prevent Emacs from asking "kill anyway" when only text properties have changed

Tags: text-properties

I have a read-only file that I open in Emacs. I have created a keyboard shortcut to hide some regions of the file. For example:

```
(defun hide-beginning ()
  (interactive)
  (setq buffer-read-only nil)
  (put-text-property 1 10 'invisible t)
  (setq buffer-read-only t)
  )
```

However, when I exit the buffer with `kill-buffer` or rather `ido-kill-buffer`, I get the question

```
Buffer myfile.txt modified; kill anyway? (yes or no)
```

How can this question be avoided?

Comment: If you only care about changes that occur in this function, you can probably use `buffer-modified-p` and `set-buffer-modified-p` to store the modified state and restore it after changing the properties.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly! I just put `(set-buffer-modified-p nil)` after I changed the property..

Comment: @ChrisR: I didn't see your comment before posting. Could you post your comment as an answer so that it could be accepted?

Comment: @HåkonHægland You might want to save value of calling `buffer-modified-p` at the beginning of the function. That way, if something else modifies the buffer, you will still be prompted about it.

Comment: If you're setting text properties which aren't meant to be saved in a file or copied and yanked, you should probably use [overlays](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlays.html#Overlays) instead of text properties. See also [What are overlays for, and how do they differ from text properties?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2200/what-are-overlays-for-and-how-do-they-differ-from-text-properties)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only care about changes that occur in this function, you can use `buffer-modified-p` and `set-buffer-modified-p` to store the modified state and restore it after changing the properties.

Answer (score 2):

The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Modification.html) notes that you can use `set-buffer-modified-p` with a `nil` argument to flag the buffer as unmodified.  Hence, if you want your function not to modify the buffer, you could do the following:

```
(defun hide-beginning ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buffer-read-only nil)
        (buffer-modified (buffer-modified-p)))
    (put-text-property 1 10 'invisible t)
    (set-buffer-modified-p buffer-modified)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Don't you need to restore `buffer-read-only` at the end of the function?

Comment: @HåkonHægland: when you `let`-bind `buffer-read-only`, you are binding it dynamically for the lifespan of the function -- basically, you're temporarily overriding its value.

Comment: @HåkonHægland the best approach is to letbind `inhibit-read-only` to t. That will cover more cases than just setting buffer-read-only to nil.

Comment: Unconditionally marking the buffer as unmodified is very dangerous. You should do that only if the buffer was unmodified in the first place, otherwise this has a high risk of resulting in unsaved changes sooner or later.

Answer (score 2):

The macro `with-silent-modifications` (in `subr.el`) seems to exist for exactly this use case:

```
Execute BODY, pretending it does not modify the buffer.
...
Typically used around modifications of text-properties which do
not really affect the buffer's content.
```