Preview horizontal rule within org mode
As per the documentation:

A line consisting of only dashes, and at least 5 of them, is exported as a horizontal line.

But is there a way to preview the horizontal rule right within emacs, similar to org-hide-emphasis-markers?

You have at least two options. One option is to insert a longer sequence of hyphens:
(defun insert-horizontal-rule ()
  (interactive)
  (insert (make-string 60 ?\-)))
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c -") 'insert-horizontal-rule)

Another option, in case you want to use a different character, is to add an overlay to a sequence of 5 or more hyphens.
(defun org-add-hr-overlays ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((line-char (if (and (display-graphic-p)
                            (char-displayable-p ?─))
                       ?─
                     ?=)))
    (remove-overlays (point-min) (point-max) 'org-hr t)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "^\\(-----+\\)$" nil t)
        (let ((ov (make-overlay (match-beginning 1)
                                (match-end 1))))
          (overlay-put ov 'org-hr t)
          (overlay-put ov 'display
                       (propertize (make-string 60 line-char)
                                   'face
                                   '(:foreground inherit))))))))

(defun org-refresh-hr-overlays ()
  (interactive)
  (when (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
    (org-add-hr-overlays)))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-add-hr-overlays)
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'org-refresh-hr-overlays)
(add-hook 'after-change-functions
          (lambda (beg end len)
            (org-refresh-hr-overlays)))

(defun insert-horizontal-rule ()
  (interactive)
  (insert (make-string 5 ?\-))
  (org-refresh-hr-overlays))


This is interesting, I wasn't aware of overlays. If I understand it right, the overlay displays 5 or more hyphens with 60 line-chars right? Does it mean if I resize the emacs window the hr will be wrapped?

useful reference: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2200/36093

The width is hard-coded so the line won't auto-adjust if that's what you want. My guess is you can use window-body-width to change its size dynamically.
